# doctrine oneToOne unidirectional: get mapped object

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, associations, one-to-one

I have three simple entities: `RecipeEntity`, `IngredientEntity` and `FoodEntity`.

As I understand doctrine associations correctly `RecipeEntity` should have a *bidirectional* oneToMany relationship to `IngredientEntity` as one recipe holds many ingredients.
One ingredient holds exactly one food, so I assume a *unidirectional* association from ingredient to food.
As IDs I have Uuids instead of integers using a third-party library, which generally works fine.

Now, I have my SQL-database filled with a recipe pointing to ingredients pointing to food.
When I call a recipe, I can retrieve the ingredients.
While looping through the ingredients, I can access the recipe (*bidirectional* association) as an object.

**But**, when I want to access the food, I don't get a `FoodEntity` object as I would have expected, but only the id of the food (which is an object itself because of the uuid library which is used).

Why don't I get a `FoodEntity` object?
What is wrong?

Hope, I made myself clear!
Thanks for Your help.

Cheers,
LT.

That's what I have (reduced for better readability):

```php
/**
 * Class RecipeEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RecipeRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="recipe")
 *
 */
class RecipeEntity implements ArraySerializableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="uuid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IngredientEntity", mappedBy="recipe")
      */
    private $ingredients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ingredients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getIngredients()
    {
        return $this->ingredients;
    }
}

/**
 * Class IngredientEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredient", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="recipe_id", columns={"recipe_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="food_id", columns={"food_id"})})
 */
class IngredientEntity implements ArraySerializableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="uuid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="recipe_id", type="uuid")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RecipeEntity", inversedBy="ingredients")
     */
    private $recipe;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="food_id", type="uuid")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FoodEntity")
     */
    private $food;
}

/**
 * Class FoodEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="food", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="source_id", columns={"source_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="LT\Model\Repository\FoodRepository")
 */
class FoodEntity implements ArraySerializableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="uuid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you make is that you add both `@Column` as well as `@OneToOne` (in case of food) and `@ManyToOne` (in case of recipe). A property is either an relation/association or a field/column, not both.

You should remove your `@Column` annotations from the associations in your entity definitions.

```
/**
 * Class IngredientEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredient", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="recipe_id", columns={"recipe_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="food_id", columns={"food_id"})})
 */
class IngredientEntity implements ArraySerializableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="uuid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RecipeEntity", inversedBy="ingredients")
     */
    private $recipe;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FoodEntity")
     */
    private $food;
}
```